# How to hide names of roads in ng-map

Tags: angularjs, ng-map

I am creating a basic map with [ng-Map](https://ngmap.github.io/). I want to hide names of all roads/streets.
 How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

you can hide the road/street name by setting your own styles, and then set the styles to google map by `map.setOptions({styles: customeStyles});`

check this [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/FDzuDJvCsxgPy3mipaKA?p=preview).